# How to run javascript on a server all the time without requesting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I want to automate process of adding amazon products to cart as soon as they get in stock. So that I get notified about that.

for that I want to run javascript code on a server computer all the time even i am not using my computer anymore.
It makes no sense if I run it on my computer and it checks the prices every single hour and my computers memory got full Its just annoying.

I wonder if Its possible. I am a MERN stack guy.

Comment: yes, it is possible to run javascript without getting requests - simple example of a nodejs server ... https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/

Comment: If i Publish the JavaScript file on a server like amazon s3 then the script will be running 24/7?

Comment: Does amazon s3 let you run a node process?

Comment: Ohh sorry my bad.

Comment: I mean to say that if i publish the script on heroku then will it be running 24/7.